# C# Linq Conditional Cast object to EF table Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Currently have

```
var orders = (from x in _contextComet.vwOrderSummary)
if (StartDate != null) 
{
    orders = orders.Where(x => x.DateCreated >= StartDate);
}
```

Now I need to change it to the following and then use the queryable object for further filtering within the same function.

```
if (inTestMode)
{
    var orders = (from x in _contextComet.vwOrderSummaryTest)
}
else
{
    var orders = (from x in _contextComet.vwOrderSummary)
}
if (StartDate != null) 
{
    orders = orders.Where(x => x.DateCreated >= StartDate);
}
```

Comment: What's your question? `var` infers a type at compile time. It's not a dynamic type. If your second snippet is an attempt to declare the same reference as two alternate types in two different places, and then use it out of scope for either declaration, that's not going to work. You might be able to do something with a single non-generic `IQueryable orders;`, but that would depend on what you're doing with the results.

Comment: `var orders = (from x in _contextComet.vwOrderSummary)
if (StartDate != null) 
{
    orders = orders.Where(x => x.DateCreated >= StartDate);
}` This wont compile

Comment: I would avoid this kind of code entirely.  Instead of baking "test modes" into your production code, use a different connection string in EF to connect to a test database, or use a mock.  Find some other way to do this besides creating "test modes" in production software.

Comment: so you have 3 things called `orders` i believe this is the root of your issue!! regard less of that you are not showing enough code.

Answer (score 1):

```
IQueryable<OrderSummary> orders = inTestMode ?
    _contextComet.vwOrderSummaryTest.Select(item => 
        new OrderSummary { /*Populate properties*/ }) :
    _contextComet.vwOrderSummary; //Assuming item type of table is OrderSummary

if (StartDate != null) 
{
    orders = orders.Where(x => x.DateCreated >= StartDate);
}
```

**Better Approach:** 
By the names of your tables (`vwOrderSummary`, `vwOrderSummaryTest`) I'd say you are mixing dev and prod environment. Do not check for the debug mode vs prod mode and by that select from different tables but have 2 separate databases and depending on mode plug a different connection string. This can be done with MSBuild nicely.

Comment: I have 2 views in SQL Server and now need to change the depending on the inTestMode boolean. Both views are identical but one filters a date range and the other does not. The class OrderSummary exists in the project and can be used for both views as they have the same fields. I tired Gilad Green method and get the error Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Common.Model.OrderSummary>' and 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<DAL.EF.CometDb.vwOrderSummary>'

Comment: IQueryable<OrderSummary> orders = inTestMode ?
            _contextComet.vwOrderSummaryAlls.Select(item => new OrderSummary { ID = item.ID }) :
            _contextComet.vwOrderSummaries;

            if (StartDate != null) orders = orders.Where(x => x.DateCreated >= StartDate);

Answer (score 1):

Got it thanks to Gilad added .ProjectTo();

```
IQueryable<OrderSummary> orders = inTestMode ?
_contextComet.vwOrderSummaryAlls.Select(item => new OrderSummary { ID = item.ID }) :
_contextComet.vwOrderSummaries.ProjectTo<OrderSummary>();
```

Comment: Glad it helped you find the solution. Please do keep in mind that mixing test and prod environments are not a good practice